# tortoiseSVN server side hook by Python

Tags: python, batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn

I need to manage the version of a project by using the revision. For this, I want to use a hook scripts at server side not at client side. To do this, I need to put an exe file or a bat file in the hooks folder in server side SVN folder. But Python file didn't work! By using an exe file by C language is working but I don't have a library to do SVN works. So I want to use Python but bat file to execute the Python file is not work and most of bat commands don't work properly.

This is my code.

pre-commit.bat (I already check path for python.)

```
echo Checking Status > con
python.exe pre-commit_PYTHON.py %*
pause < con > con
```

pre-commit_PYTHON.py

```
import subprocess

svn_info = subprocess.check_output("svnversion -n")
#svn_info = subprocess.check_output("svn info")

f=open("D:/svnTEST/new.txt", 'w')
#f=open("file:///D:/svnTEST/server/trunk/new.txt", 'w')
f.write(svn_info)
f.close()
```

It's for testing but didn't work. So, I cannot go forward to touch the SVN files or folders and I am just trying to make a window file to check python works well and get svn info well, cause bat commands don't work well too!

At client side, Hook Scripts at Setting, it works well. I don't know why... Please help this poor engineer.